# Error when trying to install Boost libraries in Cygwin via bootstrap.sh

Tags: boost

I downloaded boost 1.61.0 and unzipped it in the following directory:
C:\Users\Kenneth\Desktop\tuxedo\boost_1_61_0\boost_1_61_0

When I enter the command
    ./bootstrap.sh
I get the following error:
    /b2lding Boost.Build engine with toolset gcc... tools/build/src/engine/bin.ntx86
    cp: cannot stat './tools/build/src/engine/bin.ntx86'$'\r''/b2': No such file or directory
    cp: cannot stat './tools/build/src/engine/bin.ntx86'$'\r''/bjam': No such file or directory

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Ken

Answer (score 0):

to use `*.sh` based configuration you need to have posix compatible system. On windows is called `cygwin`. So install `cygwin`, get `gcc toolchain` and try again inside cygwin terminal. This should help you. However in `cygwin` you could install already compiled libs - this will save you some time.